# class constructor with structure array (direct)

Tags: c++, arrays, class, initialization, structure

UPDATE:

i see im causing much confusion in here, sry bout that guys.. thanks Roman for the idea with the vectors ^^

clarifing my problem: i want to get the structure-array straigth into the created class (in main()) by passing the integers as an parameter(i dont want to create global or local variables for dem arrays) and copying them into the class-member

the problem is im failing at the initialization of the class, my attempt:

```
struct _Note
{
    int nFrequenz;
    int nTakt;
};

class _Chart
{
public:
    _Chart( std::vector<_Note> vNotes )
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < vNotes.size(); i++ )
            this->_chart.push_back( vNotes[i] ); 
    }

private:
    std::vector<_Note> _chart;
};

void main()
{
    _Chart x(
        { {1,2}, {2,3} } 
    ); 
    // not working, wrong initialization
    // still confused about the brackets ^^

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `sizeof( p )` to be without a length specified for the array??? Best use a `std::vector` to fix this.

Comment: I would try making the argument type to `klasse` const, and also try using the assignment operator instead of ().

Comment: `main()` returns `int`, not `void`. Also, names starting with an underscore followed by a capital character are reserved for the implementation (compiler and standard library).

Comment: Please avoid editing your question by destroying your original question completely. This will render any existing answer useless. Prefer to put another **UPDATE** section to specify changes, or what was working for you!!

Comment: Your 'brackets' *won't work*. Just create an instance of `_Note` add it to the vector in `main()` and then pass it to the constructor. And yep, I seriously recommend you to get `vNodes` by reference if you don't want to copy your vector twice.

Answer (score 2):

When passed as a parameter `struktur p[]` decays to a pointer (similar to `struktur* p`). The size of this pointer will definitely not be what you're looking for in determining the number of elements.

Instead, why not provide a two iterator constructor similar to the standard containers?

Comment: yes, `sizeof(p) == sizeof(uintptr_t)` which is 4 for x86 machines

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the element count too:

```
klasse( struktur p[], size_t count )
{
    _chart = new struktur[count];
    // copy array in one shot as no deep copy is needed here.
    memcpy(_chart, p, count * sizeof(struktur));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An array decays to a pointer when passed. So, you must pass the count of elements in the array as an additional parameter to the function. However, in this scenario, you have an option.

Move the `glob` definition to above the `klasse` declaration. Then in the constructor you should be able to get the count of objects with `sizeof(glob)/sizeof(struktur);`. You should be able to dynamic allocate and do a member wise copy there after.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use the std::vector container template?

```
class klasse
{
public:
    klasse(std::vector<struktur>& strs)
    {
        _chart = new struktur[strs.size()];
        for( int i = 0; i < strs.size(); i++ )
        {
            this->_chart[i] = strs[i];
        }
    }

private:
    struktur* _chart;
};
```

And in main():

```
void main()
{
    std::vector<struktur> myStructs;

    myStruct.push_back(glob[0]);
    myStruct.push_back(glob[1]);
    myStruct.push_back(glob[2]);

    klasse y(myStructs); 
    getchar();
}
```

This is simple and elegant.

**[Upd.]** Yes, here in your example `sizeof(p)` will be equals to `sizeof(uintptr_t`) because p is a pointer type.

Comment: Why not using the `std::vector` as a member in 1st place?

Comment: Well, yes. But the question was "how to initialize" and I've just showed how to. std::vector as a member and std::copy this is fine too.